# LibreOffice 3.3.2 "Export to PDF" option doesn't work

Tags: 11.04, libreoffice, kubuntu

After installing Natty 11.04 (Kubuntu), I noticed that the "Export to PDF" menu item doesn't work. I am thinking about doing an uninstall-reinstall.

Has anyone else had this problem, or it is a known bug? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to uninstall & reinstall, simply go to your home folder, press CTRL & H to show the hidden folders, look for **.libreoffice** and delete it.  That is the profile for LibreOffice and in essence should resolve the problem.

I should have also stated that when you next start LibreOffice a new .libreoffice profile will happen.

Comment: Thanks. There was a problem in LibreOffice, Tools, Properties

Answer (score 1):

I have to open Tools -> Customize and from there I have to reset menu "File". After that was export OK.

Comment: @Tarmo I think this really *is* an answer (not a comment), but I'm having trouble understanding what it's telling me to do. Can you edit this to explain in greater detail what you're suggesting should be done? In particular, it's unclear what changes need to be made in Tools > Customize. "reset menu 'File'" doesn't really make sense without greater context. In addition to more explanatory text, you might consider posting a screenshot.